# getDay() me devuelve 1 en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código para obtener la fecha.

```
var f = new Date();
f.getDay();
```

y cuando quiero obtener el día con el método `getDay()` obtengo el valor 1 pero hoy es 28.

Comment: te deje una respuesta totalmente explicada para qu3e comprendas mejor por que se esta presentando lo que mencionas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso pasa por que tienes dos maneras de obtener el día:

1. getDate(); Lo obtiene en un formato de 1 al 31
2. getDay(); Lo obtiene en un formato de 0 al 6

Entonces si quieres mostrar la fecha debes hacer lo siguiente

```js
const dia = new Date().getDate()
console.log(dia)
```

Ahora si lo que buscas es obtener que ubicación en la semana tiene un día en específico, entonces hazlo así

```js
const dia = new Date().getDay()
console.log(dia)
```

> Debes entender que para el caso de getDay() se cuentan los días como
>   si fuera un array en la posición 0: domingo, posición 1: lunes y así
>   sucesivamente hasta llegar al 6

```
|    0   |   1   |   2   |   3   |   4   |   5   |   6   |
|--------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|Domingo | Lunes | Martes| Mierc | Jueves| Viern | Sabado|
```

---

> En cambio getDate() te va a dar el número que dentro del calendario
>   correspondiente a la fecha, es decir hoy es 28 y por lo tanto eso es
>   el día que te devuelve

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es que `Date.getDay()` devuelve el dia de la semana, no del mes 1 corresponderia a lunes, si el calendario por defecto comienza en domingo, para obtener el dia del mes tienes que usar `Date.getDate()`.

```
let fecha = new Date();
console.log(fecha.getDate());  //devolvera la fecha actual
```